# How to recover bookmarks and settings in Space File Manager?

Tags: data-recovery, settings, filemanager, bookmarks

I'm using Space File Manager instead of Nautilus. Yesterday my laptop became non-responsive and hence I did a hard restart (hold down power button for 5-10 seconds). After restart, all my bookmarks and settings in Space File Manager are gone! Is there any way to recover the bookmarks? If not, is there at least a way to backup the bookmarks and settings so that if it repeats again, I can restore them.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS